# List struct revealing the details of the ADT

Tags: c, list, struct, interface

I am studying through a book named `C Interfaces and Implementation` by `David R. Hanson`. There are some ideas about his given List ADT that I can't quite get.

We define a List type as follows:

```
#ifndef LIST_INCLUDED
#define LIST_INCLUDED

#define T List_T

typedef struct T *T;
struct T {
    T rest; 
    void *first;
};
```

Here I can see that List is built in head-and-tail fashion that I am familiar with. I see that List_T is a pointer to the struct defined to hold the relevant node data and T is an alias to that. The part I don't get is that doesn't C compiler gets confused by the usage of same type name T as both the name of the struct and the name of pointer to it? What I would use in my implementation is as follows:

```
typedef struct List* list_t;
struct List {
    list_t rest;
    void *first;
};
```

so that the names are different for struct and typedefed pointer type to that struct. Do both work correctly?

And also `David R. Hanson` says following about this List definition:

> A List_T is a pointer to a struct List_T. Most ADTs hide the representation details of their types. List reveals these details because for this
>   particular ADT, the complications induced by the alternatives outweigh
>   the benefits of doing so... Revealing List_T’s representation simplifies the interface and its use in several ways. For example, variables of type struct List_T can be defined and initialized statically, which is useful for building lists at compile time, and avoids allocations. Likewise, other structures can have struct List_Ts embedded in them.

How this ADT reveals its internals? I mean, aren't all ADTs in C that way? As far as I know, C does not have built in data hiding mechanisms. And how this relates to our ability to initialize this structure statically and embedding in other structures?

Note: I looked at many meta posts to see what is the guidelines to follow if I am  to post a portion of source code from a book. I couldn't find any clarifications. But I assumed it should be OK since the code is distributed under MIT license. If this poses a problem, please notify me.

Comment: In my experience, in C you should not hide pointer with typedef.

Comment: @Stargateur Well, I too think passing pointers explicitly and always reminding your users that list is actually a pointer to nodes is better. But David Hanson tried to give a high level interface as much as possible, I guess.

Comment: Structure tags are in one namespace; typedef names are in another.  There is no problem with `typedef struct Wotsit Wotsit;` — the first `Wotsit` is a struct tag and the second is a regular name.  You can have opaque types in C.  You simply use a `Wotsit` pointer and as long as you don't try to dereference the structure to access the members, you don't have to specify the details of what elements are in the structure.  This a good way of doing information hiding in general, though Hanson is not using it with this type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I can have above `struct Wotsit Wotsit;` definition and other function declarations that work on `Wotsit *` in a .h file but I can give all the implementation and full structure definition in a .c file, as I understood it.  So that users of my libs including .h files can't rely on my internal representation of `Wotsit` ?

Comment: That's correct.  The implementation knows the structure; the consumers do not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But I don't get how this relates to our ability to statically initialize lists at compile time and embedding them in other structs.

Comment: Because it is not opaque, you can do things like `struct List_T X = { 0, "Aardvark" };` which you couldn't if it was opaque.  You could also create an array of them and have the links set to point to each other.

Comment: For anyone reaching here in the future, they can also take a look at `Section 11.4, Opaque structures` of the freely available book `Modern C` by @JensGustedt . These comments here and that section helps to  clarify things.